# Code Previously used to remove subtotal from a pivot table in excel using vba not working now

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have been using a vba code to create pivot tables and remove grand & sub-totals for a couple of weeks now. The subtotal part of the code which was previously working well is not throwing the following error

```
Run-Time Error '1004': Unable to set the Subtotals property of the PivotField Class
```

and i an not to figure whats causing it.

Below is the code, Appreciate any help.

Regards

```
Sub Pivottable_5()

    Dim objTable As PivotTable
    Dim objField As PivotField

    ' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All Proj").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    ' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard

    ' Specify row and column fields.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Products")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Product")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Value Category")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    objField.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Driven?")
    objField.Orientation = xlPageField
    objField.PivotItems("No").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("Not Classified").Visible = False

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Project Status")
    objField.Orientation = xlPageField
    objField.PivotItems("Cancelled").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("Suspended").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("Scoped not active").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("SPA Business Unit")
    objField.Orientation = xlPageField
    objField.PivotItems("-").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("Not Classified").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("Plth").Visible = False
    objField.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False

    ' Specify a data field with its summary
    ' function and format.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2014 Actual Total")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2015 Actual Total")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2016 Actual Total")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2016 Forecast Total")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2017 Forecast Total")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2018 Forecast Total")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2019 Forecast Total")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    ActiveSheet.name = "iNexus Pivot"

    ' Rename the pivot table
    With Sheets("iNexus Pivot")
        .PivotTables(1).name = "PivotTable2"
    End With

    With Sheets("iNexus Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ColumnGrand = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowGrand = False

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iFieldMax As Integer

     'Find the number of PivotFields
    iFieldMax = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields.Count

     'Loop through the fields in the Pivot
    For i = 1 To iFieldMax

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields(i)

             'Set subtotal calculation to nothing
            .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)

        End With

    Next i

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80

    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select

    ' Move the cursor to the sheet with the buttons
    Application.Goto Reference:="Sheet1!R1C1"

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Did your source data change in any significant way?

Comment: @Tom: Sorry i dont follow you question. Are u asking if i am using a different data source?

Comment: Yep. If you code worked fine until now and hasn't change, you have to look at the things, that did change. :) Btw, which line throws the error?

Comment: @Tom: The subtotals part of the code is whats throwing an error. The snippet towards the end of the code with the "FALSE".

Comment: My first guess would be, that the number of subtotals changed, and therefore the number of `False`s is wrong, Maybe also take a look at this solution, it should work for different counts of subtotals for future imports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170895/pivottable-do-not-show-subtotals

Comment: @Tom: Ya i have seen that thread before, that snippet of code also didnt work. The subtotal part of the code gets into a long loop and then throws the error.

Comment: Hm, okay. I think I need to see some of the data you feed into this script to make a more educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing similar problem. The issue is Office 365 update. After update, code does not work. Had to roll back. There is nice page for that:

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-revert-to-the-previous-version-of-office-365/