# Macro to insert Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to use a macro to create a pivot table. I have used the record macro and followed the steps through, but I am getting an error and not very well versed in VBA. It keeps getting hung up on the last line of the following... not sure why... can anyone help?

```
Sheets.Add.Name = "Inventory Summary"
Worksheets("Inventory Summary").Move _
    after:=Worksheets("Info")
Sheets("Inventory").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Table2", Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Inventory Summary!R2C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=8
```

I have recorded this step in a macro and it worked fine.  I added this to a larger macro (multiple 'steps').  When I run the complete Macro I get an error to debug and it brings me to the point referenced above. but i cannot see what is wrong...

Comment: *TableName:="PivotTable1"* Do you have an existing pivottable with this name ?

Comment: What is the error number and text?

Answer (score 1):

It's often cleaner to split up the two commands which create the pivotcache and the pivottable (and use some variables):

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or eg ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets("Info"))
    ws.Name = "Inventory Summary"
    
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                          SourceData:="Table2", Version:=8)
                          
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A2"), _
                   TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=8)

End Sub
```

If that still doesn't work then you need to tell us exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: This did the trick --- is there a way to change the Pivot Table Options>Display>Classic Pivot Table Grid
... and prevent subtotaling of field "Plant"

Comment: You can record a macro while making changes to the pivot table - it will give you the lines you need, and you can add those to your code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170895/pivottable-do-not-show-subtotals covers subtotals.

Comment: i did try that... but it did not change as expected - actually looked the same thx - i will keep searching...