"Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" on Pivot table macro in Excel
can someone please help me with this macro I am trying to get working. If I am being honest I don't have much experience with macros and used chatGPT as a resource to write this code. It was working but no matter what I do I keep on running into this error.
This is my code:
Sub CreateReport()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pivotWs As Worksheet
    Dim pivotTbl As PivotTable
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim todaysDate As String
    
    ' Step 1: Delete column J
    Columns("J:J").Delete
    
    ' Step 2: Add 2 new rows to the top
    Rows("1:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
    ' Step 3: Type "PB Charge Review by WQ" in cell A1
    Range("A1").Value = "PB Charge Review by WQ"
    
    ' Step 4: Merge cells A1 and B1
    Range("A1:B1").Merge
    
    ' Step 5: Bold cell A1 and make the font 12 pt
    With Range("A1")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With
    
    ' Step 6: Align the text in cell A1 to the left
    Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    
    ' Step 7: Underline cells A3:I3 (headers)
    Range("A3:I3").Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    
    ' Step 8: Autofit columns A-I
    Columns("A:I").AutoFit
    
    ' Step 9: Rename the sheet to today's date (mmddyy)
    todaysDate = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
    ActiveSheet.Name = todaysDate
    
    ' Step 10: Add a new sheet and move it to the beginning
    Set pivotWs = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1))
    
    ' Step 11: Rename this new sheet to "Data Pivot"
    pivotWs.Name = "Data Pivot"
    
    ' Step 12: Set the data range for the pivot table
    Set ws = Sheets(todaysDate)
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A3:I" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Step 13: Create the pivot table in the new sheet
    Set pivotTbl = pivotWs.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=dataRange), TableDestination:=pivotWs.Cells(1, 1))
    
    ' Step 14-19: Add fields to the pivot table and format them
    With pivotTbl
        ' Add "Owning Area" to rows
        .PivotFields("Owning Area").Orientation = xlRowField
        
        ' Add "Num of Chg Sess" to values as a sum
        With .PivotFields("Num of Chg Sess")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlSum
        End With
        
        ' Add "Amt on Chg Rvw" to values as a sum
        With .PivotFields("Amt on Chg Rvw")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlSum
        End With
        
        ' Add "Avg Svc Dt Age" to values as an average
        With .PivotFields("Avg Svc Dt Age")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlAverage
        End With
        
        ' Add "Avg Age" to values as an average
        With .PivotFields("Avg Age")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlAverage
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Step 20: Format columns B, D, and E with custom number format to show dashes instead of zeros
    pivotWs.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0;–"
    pivotWs.Columns(4).NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0;–"
    pivotWs.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0;–"
    
    ' Step 21: Format column C as currency with no decimals
    pivotWs.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    
End Sub

Pretty much what I want my macro to do is to do some formatting on the first sheet, then rename that sheet to today's date mmddyyyy. Then I want it to create a new sheet titled "Data Pivot" and move that tab to the front so it is the first thing you see.
Then I want to add a pivot table at cell A1 for the "Data Pivot" sheet using information from my first sheet. The headers are in A3:I3 and the macro should go all the way down to the last filled cell in column A. However, with the error I am getting my macro is only going until when I create a new sheet named "Data Pivot."
When I click debug, it says that my error is at line:
Set pivotTbl = pivotWs.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=dataRange), TableDestination:=pivotWs.Cells(1, 1))


It would help to split the creation of the PivotCache and the PivotTable into two steps.

For BigBen's suggestion see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77426842/478884
