Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument - Shared Macro
I am running into an issue with a macro shared to me that takes raw data and transforms it into a pivot table.
I know the problem lies within the naming convention of the original recorder's naming convention or file path, but I can't figure out what to change. Any assistance would be helpful.
Sub Cherwell_Daily()
'
' Cherwell_Daily Macro
' Cherwell Daily Report
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.71
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Export Data!R1C1:R1048576C10", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=7
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Owned By")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Incident ID"), "Count of Incident ID", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "SLA Resolve By Deadline")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Pivot"
    Range("B15").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$93").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Resolved"
    Rows("1:66").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Weekly 081522.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Cherwell_Daily"
    Windows("Res 081522.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D103").Select
    Windows("Weekly 081522.xlsx").Activate
    Application.Left = -1013.75
    Application.Top = 80.5
    Sheets("Export Data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.Left = -1148
    Application.Top = 97
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Cherwell_Daily"
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Rows("2:2").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("4:4").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Rows("6:71").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=60
    Rows("73:82").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Rows("84:88").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Range("D92").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-102
    Sheets("Pivot").Select
End Sub


Which line throws the error?

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Export Data!R1C1:R1048576C10", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
:=7

It would help to split the creation of the PivotCache and the PivotTable into two steps. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77426842 for example.

Also try removing optional parameters, e.g. Version:=7, TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _ :=7

@BigBen, Removing the optional parameters worked, didn't need to separate out the steps. Thank you!!
